# Are there Fourier Eigenfunctions "Outside" an Interval?

Tags: fourier-transform

1) It is known that no function vanishing outside an interval $-a < x < a  $ has a Fourier transform with compact support.  $(x,a \in \mathbb{R})$ However, are there Fourier transform pairs which both vanish inside the interval $-a < x < a$, and are Fourier transform eigenfunctions with this property?

In other words, for all $f(x)$:
$$  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \Pi (\frac{x}{a})e^{-i2 \pi xy} \, dx \neq  \lambda f(x) \Pi (\frac{x}{a})$$
However, are there functions, $g(x)$, solving this?:
$$  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) (1-\Pi (\frac{x}{a}))e^{-i2 \pi xy} \, dx =  \lambda g(x) (1-\Pi (\frac{x}{a}))$$

$N.B.$ - $\Pi (\frac{x}{a})$ is the $rect(x)$ function scaled to a width of $a$.

2) Are there keywords or names for this topic, that I might do more research?  $i.e.$ Is there a specific name for this domain "outside an interval?"

Comment: Eigenfunctions of Fourier transforms are all expressible in terms of Hermite polynomials, so none of them vanishes on an interval.

Comment: The Dirac comb vanishes on $(0,1)$ and is its own Fourier transform, but it is a (tempered) distribution.

Comment: Thanks, @Fan-Zheng, but due to the degeneracy of Hermite functions, a weighted sum of Hermite functions can be constructed to form new a eigenfunction.  The question is whether the new eigenfunction can be forced to zero inside the interval?

Comment: @EEatWork It really depends on what kind of weighted sum you allow. Note that all the Hermite polynomials are holomorphic, so if your sum converges well enough, the limit would also be holomorphic, which then cannot vanish on an interval. On the other hand, if you allow generalized functions like the Dirac comb, then there are counterexamples.

Comment: Yes the Hermite functions have eigenvalue $(-i)^n$ so you can sum 1/4 of them, but as Fan Zheng said, any convergent sum will be analytic so it can't vanish on an interval

Comment: Thanks, @user1952009 and Fan-Zheng.  Pointing out that non-trivial holomorphic functions don't vanish on an interval does help me out a lot; I appreciate it! ... I would accept distributions for an answer, but the Dirac comb(x) multiplied by rect(x) does not transform to a Dirac comb (y) multiplied by rect(y), unless one admits vanishing "almost everywhere."

Comment: @EEatWork The Dirac comb transforms to itself, and it's easy to pick an interval on which it vanishes.

Comment: Sure, but I specified the interval to be symmetric about the origin: -a<x<a.